# Why python -m xxx not get the right __name__ value?

Tags: python

Now I have a very simple test python file, I want it as a module

```
# hello.py
print(__name__)
```

Then I test two commands:

```
python -m hello
python -m hello.py
```

The first output `__name__` is `__main__`, this is what I can't explain
The second output `__name__` is 'hello' I expected, but there is a error messsage

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'hello.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: `__path__` attribute not found on 'hello' while trying to find 'hello.py'). Try using 'hello' instead of 'hello.py' as the module name.
```

Can you explain for me why the first situation the `__name__` is `__main__` and what`s the differcent between the two commands.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When using .py, python will look for the file in your working directory.

Comment: `-m` takes a module name, not a file name. As a module name, `hello.py` means a submodule named `py` in a package named `hello`. You do not have such a package or submodule.

Comment: Every Python script when executed as a main entry point of the program gets a `__name__` of `"__main__"`. That's how we tell if we are running some module or just importing it for use in different place.

Comment: *"The first output __name__ is __main__, this is what I can't explain"* This is the expected behaviour as documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#what-is-the-top-level-code-environment

Comment: So I have to make `hello` as a folder, then add __main__.py and __init__.py files to make it as a   module?

Comment: @XuWang. No, it already is a module. But when you run it using `python -m hello` it has `__name__ == '__main__'`. If you instead run `python` interactively and then use `import hello` then `__name__` will have another name like `hello`.